# Django Renaming/Refactoring a Custom User Model

Tags: python, django, model, django-migrations, django-database

I have a custom user model: `class CustomUser(AbstractUser):` already migrated and populated with some records. I want to rename this `CustomUser` to `MyUserModel`. In Pycharm I right-clicked on the name and chose `refactor` - `rename` so every reference to this model is also renamed.

I then ran `python3 manage.py makemigrations` which gave me the below error:

`"AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`

So I went to `myproject.settings` and changed the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to `MyUserModel`.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.MyUserModel'
```

The `makemigrations` then worked. and when I looked into the migration file it looked like this:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0011_update_proxy_permissions'),
        ('users', '0002_auto_20190916_0658'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='MyUserModel',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
                ('username', models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, unique=True, validators=[django.contrib.auth.validators.UnicodeUsernameValidator()], verbose_name='username')),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, verbose_name='first name')),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150, verbose_name='last name')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=254, verbose_name='email address')),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.', verbose_name='staff status')),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.', verbose_name='active')),
                ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='date joined')),
                ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
                ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'user',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'users',
                'abstract': False,
            },
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='CustomUser',
        ),
    ]
```

I guess migration manager did not detect the rename but is creating the new table. Which I do not mind since I dont have important data yet.

when I then run `python3 manage.py migrate` the below error occurs:

```
ValueError: The field account.EmailAddress.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'users.myusermodel', but app 'users' doesn't provide model 'myusermodel'.
The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'users.myusermodel', but app 'users' doesn't provide model 'myusermodel'.
The field authtoken.Token.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'users.myusermodel', but app 'users' doesn't provide model 'myusermodel'.
The field socialaccount.SocialAccount.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'users.myusermodel', but app 'users' doesn't provide model 'myusermodel'.
```

Why is this happening? I also tried a migration with `RenameModel` rather than creating a new table and deleting the old one. Still got the same error.

Comment: Update `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings to new modified name

Comment: I just said that I already did otherwise `makemigrations` command will not work.

Comment: please show your setting.py of `AUTH_USER_MODEL`

Comment: this is it: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.MyUserModel'`

Comment: Please also update it in installed apps in settings.py.

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool you are not making any sense. I did not change the app name. this is a model name.  A model name has nothing to do with the INSTALLED_APPS